# sony vaio cw 1600x900 screen with vpccw21fx mainboard, showing as 1366 x 768

Tags: laptop, resolution, sony-vaio

I had the mainboard in sony vaio vpccw2c5e (with 1600x900 screen) broken and mistakenly bought a mainboard for vpccw21fx thinking the model number was the same (it was but I guess I missed some minor differences).

After connecting the mainboard to the screen it only shows as 1366 x 768 - stretched, top on the bottom, what have you.

Is there any way to force the GPU on the new mainboard to output 1600x900 resolution?

The GPU on the new mainboard is nvidia 310M. The old one was 330M. The laptop has hdmi port and should handle 1080p without problems.

*EDIT:*
This happens on POST screen and in BIOS, before even booting the OS. I have both Linux and Windows 7 installed, so solution using any of these 2 is OK.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned what Windows so I'll assume Windows 7 however if its 8 should be the same(ish).

If you go to desktop right click then go to Screen Resolution, then click on Advanced Settings and List All Modes you should be able to pick a non-recommended Resolution out of this list.

However be very careful this is not recommended and you might loose your display all together if its not supported in which case it should return after about 30 seconds if you go not press any keys.

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Will try this. Anyway this happens on boot screen before even running the OS. Will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Nothing you can do on boot, that will just be what the motherboard is defaulting too. Problem is that when motherboards for laptops are manufactured they will be set to the resolution of the screen (hardwired). The best you can do is trick the board in Windows using the above but its hit and miss if it will work. The external HDMI will be more flexible because the manufacture cannot determine what you will plug that in to...

Comment: Ok, as long as it works in the OS I don't care about the POST/BIOS since it's usable anyway.

Comment: Do you know why it's choosing the non-native res in the OS? My impression was that after acquiring EDID it would switch to whatever the display is telling the GPU it's native res is.

Comment: Yeah Boot/Bios is unimportant. Linux you need to use xrandr in terminal but its been a while so would have to give that a google on how to set a custom resolution, however test in windows first to give you an indication of how well it works before setting in Linux as it might not be reversible (not sure if it switches back like Windows if set to a unsupported resolution)

Comment: To be honest I would have expected the GPU to detect the monitor and know what resolution is best however I must admit I've not been in your exact situation :) When you go to the Screen Resolution section in Windows under Display what does it show as the screen name/model is that correct for your laptop model or does it think its got the screen from its own model (if that makes sense)...

Comment: I think it just detects it as a generic "sony display" or something. Will confirm when I get back home.